# Git Submodule : Cannot update submodule to an earlier revision

Tags: git-submodules

I have spent a lot of time in reading and trying out git submodules. But I have really given up.

My problem:

I am cloning a git repository as a submodule. So, I do

```
git submodule add -b master url localpath
```

The repository starts downloading and a corresponding entry is made in the .gitmodules file. git submodule status shows the latest commit.

So far so good.

During the development, it was found out that the HEAD commit in the submodule has a bug. So, the commit should be changed from master to some commit id.

So, I changed the commit id ( 7 aplhanumeric ) in the .gitmodule file from branch = master

```
branch = <commitid> -> .gitmodule file
```

And did

```
git submodule update --remote
```

The error is

**Fatal: Need a single revision**

**Unable to find current origin/ revision in submodule path**

I also tried

```
 git submodule foreach git pull
```

so that it will pull the commit id, but it simply returns with

**Entering name_of_the_submodule**

**Already up to date.**

Can anyone please help me?

P.S: I have already gone through many tutorials and question and answers. So if you want to downvote this for fun, then please first point to an answer and I will delete this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have cloned the submodule as described in your question:

```
git submodule add -b master url localpath
```

Then you should be able to `changedir` to the submodule:

```
cd localpath
```

Once in the submodule, you can use any git commands and they will only affect the submodule's repo. For example, you can checkout that holy branch or revision:

```
git checkout <branch|tag|hash>
```

or checkout the second-to-last revision in master branch:

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

Then `changedir` back to the main git repo:

```
cd ..
```

And `git status` should yield something like:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitmodules
    new file:   localpath

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   localpath (new commits)
```

Then just add the *changes* done to your submodule:

```
git add localpath
```

And commit

```
git commit -m "Add submodule url to localpath with older working commit"
```

Comment: got it ! there are couple of tutorials which refers to change your .gitmodule file with <commit id>. All of them fails and thus the confusion. Its simplest to clone the whole branch ( irrespective of the commit id )  and then do a git checkout in the submodule of the commit id you want, and then do a git commit in the parent branch and then push.

Comment: There is one more thing. Other developers who have already downloaded the whole code including the submodule need to invoke git pull and then git submodule update or git submodule update --remote to sync with the latest submodule changes.

Comment: Yes, every time you change the submodule reference, when doing `git pull` on the parent repo, submodule will appear as `modified`. To update the submodule to the new reference simply run `git submodule update` on the main repo.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question, after a little bit of research, that might be helpful to the others:

It is a big pain to understand git submodules, but once you get it, everything starts making sense !

The following post shows:

- adding submodules and letting others sync with your submodules.
- updating submodules and letting others sync with your submodules.
- removing submodules and letting other sync with your submodules.
- updating the removed submodules.

**Adding submodules**

git submodule add -b

The entry in .gitmodules ( name, path, url, branch ) downloads the respective submodule by

```
git submodule update --init
```

This does three important thing, the first two of which are hidden from the user:

1. updates .git/config with an extra entry ( submodules )
2. downloads a repository in bare form under .git/modules. That means, there is .git inside a .git.
3. checks out the git submodule from the .git/modules into the parent directory.

Now, on Day 2, the commiter, who commited the submodule realises, that he should change the submodule to some other commit and not the HEAD. So, he would go to his local repository and then go the submodule path and then checkout the commit that he wants by simply invoking

```
git checkout <hash>
cd <parent dir>
git submodule status
```

At this point, the git submodule status still does not shows the new hash. The new hash will only be visible when the changes are staged. Now, the commiter, just needs to stage ( add ), commit and push the changes, so that it is visible to all the other developers.

**Updating the added submodule**

On Day 3, the other developers, would update their repository by just invoking the command

```
git pull # this is to get the latest commit of the parent git repository.
git submodule update --force # update the submodule with latest hash
```

Basically, here the point  is simple: The submodule does not react until and unless it is told to do so. Just doing git pull, wont update the git submodule. The developers can continue to work on their local submodules and not sync them to the one on the server "forever". The submodule update would happen on explicitly invoking the git submodule update command.

**Removing submodule**

Now, on Day4, the committer, decides to remove the git submodule completely. Here the steps are also not simple, because there is nothing called  git submodule rm that should have been equivalent to git submodule add. This can be done only and only if the following sequence is followed:

```
git submodule deinit submodulename
```

1. this deletes the .git/config entry.
2. this clears the submodule directory !! You will see nothing in the submdoule directory after this command.
3. But the contents of the submodule are still available under .git/modules

Hence a git status -u here will still show that Everyting is upto date !

So show the removals,

```
git rm submodulepath
```

At this point git status will return that .gitmodules has been changed ( the submodule has been deleted ) and the submodule path has been deleted. Commit and push the changes.

**Updating with removed submodule**

On Day5, the developers want to delete the submodules "automatically" like it did with git submodule update. So they do first a git pull, which succesfully removes all indices to the git submodules

```
 git submodule status # shows nothing
```

BUT, the .git/config still contains valid submodule entry and the submodule folder is there with all its contents and the bare repository under .git/submodules !  There is no command to delete them. All of them must be explicitly removed via hand..( Please correct me if I am wrong )